# Pane events inconsistent between OSX and Windows for Safari

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Using **Safari on OSX**, the Google Map v3 implementation of panes is inconsistent and is preventing marker click events from functioning depending on what pane(s) are being used.

If you enable the develop menu and then **override the User Agent to report as Safari for Windows**, the implementation then matches all other browsers (FF, IE, Chrome, etc.).  This seems to indicate that it is an issue within the Google API as all that changed was the User Agent string.

*Incidentally, adding a marker to the overlayPane (#6) actually adds the marker to the overlayShadow (#2) pane instead.  So it is not currently possible to add anything to pane 6 on any browser or platform.*

Using the following example, the issue can be observed by hovering over each marker.  If the marker receives the hover event, it will turn green.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map_canvas
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

        for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            var m = new marker(i);
            m.setMap(map);
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function marker(index) {
        this._latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397 + (index * .1), 150.644 + (index * .1));
        this._div = null;
        this._index = index;
    }
    marker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    marker.prototype.onAdd = function () {
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        var label = document.createTextNode(this._index + 1);

        div.appendChild(label);

        div.id = this._index + 1;
        div.style.border = "1px solid black";
        div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        div.style.width = "20px";
        div.style.height = "20px";
        div.style.position = "absolute";

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        });

        this._div = div;

        var panes = this.getPanes();

        switch (this._index) {
            case (0):
                panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
                break;
            case (1):
                panes.overlayShadow.appendChild(div);
                break;
            case (2):
                panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
                break;
            case (3):
                panes.floatShadow.appendChild(div);
                break;
            case (4):
                panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
                break;
            case (5):
                panes.overlayShadow.appendChild(div);
                break;
        }
    }
    marker.prototype.draw = function () {
        var projection = this.getProjection();
        if (projection) {
            var div = this._div;

            var point = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this._latlng);
            if (point && div != null) {
                div.style.left = point.x - 10 + 'px';
                div.style.top = point.y + -10 + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Has anyone found a way around this issue, or is there a fix pending?

Comment: You should post this as a bug at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=apitype:Javascript3 I didn't see any reference to a similar issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the part of your question where you say "the Google Map v3 implementation of panes is inconsistent and is preventing marker click events from functioning depending on what pane(s) are being used," the problem appears to be that you may be attempting to make use of mouse events on panes where mouse events are not intended to be used:

pane 1: `overlayLayer` - from the [api-doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes): **It may not receive DOM events.**

pane 2: `overlayShadow` - from the [api-doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes): **It may not receive DOM events.**

Regarding the part of your question that is focused on the `MapPanes`:

> *Incidentally, adding a marker to the overlayPane (#6) actually adds* 
>   *the marker to the overlayShadow (#2) pane instead. So it is not*
>   *currently possible to add anything to pane 6 on any browser or*
>   *platform*.

First, there is no `overlayPane`; if you are talking about pane 6, from bottom to top, I believe you meant to say: `floatPane`. Also, I think the problem is actually a bug in your `switch` statement code:

```
switch (this._index) {
    case (0):
        panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
        break;
    case (1):
        panes.overlayShadow.appendChild(div);
        break;
    case (2):
        panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
        break;
    case (3):
        panes.floatShadow.appendChild(div);
        break;
    case (4):
        panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
        break;
    case (5):
        // This code is a duplicate of the code in case(1):
        panes.overlayShadow.appendChild(div);
        // I believe what you want here is:
        panes.floatPane.appendChild( div );
        break;
}
```

I hope this is helpful -

Comment: Thanks for finding my bug.  Guess that's what happens when you rush.  I still wonder about the DOM events though since only the mapPane, overlayLayer and overlayShadow (layers 0, 1 & 2) are documented to possibly not receive DOM events.

Comment: No problem; glad to help. I was assuming that only the items you are placing on panes 1 & 2 (it didn't look like you were using pane 0) would be having problems with clicks. Are you having problems where items you place on the other panes (not 0,1, or 2) are not handling mouse events correctly?